# MeteorJS: User Email Verification

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

Ive sent an email verification to a user. How do I actually get them to verify after they click on the link that They receive on their address.

I've seen this function

`Accounts.onEmailVerificationLink`

but I do not know how to use it. What should be done to actually verify a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution

```js
FlowRouter.route( '/verify-email/:token', {
    name: 'verify-email',
    action( params ) {
        Accounts.verifyEmail( params.token, ( error ) => {
            if ( error ) {
                Bert.alert( error.reason, 'danger' );
            } else {
                FlowRouter.go( '/' );
                Bert.alert( 'Email verified! Thanks!', 'success' );
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I had to create that route